# Mongocxx connection error

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I installed mongocxx driver successfully. Now I tried to write a class to connect and query data from database. If I write a query in constructor like this

```
DBConnection::DBConnection()
{
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(mongocxx::uri{});
    coll = client["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    auto curs = coll.find(bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{} << finalize);
    for (auto doc: curs) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
    }
}
```

it works like a charm.

But, if I separate in two functions like this

```
DBConnection::DBConnection()
{
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(mongocxx::uri{});
    coll = client["testdb"]["testcollection"];
}

void DBConnection::loadData() {
    mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find({});
    for (auto doc: cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
    }    
}
```

then, it gave the error: `src/mongoc/mongoc-topology-scanner.c:754 mongoc_topology_scanner_get_error(): precondition failed: ts`.

I don't know why. How can I fix this?

Comment: how did you get coll from one function to the other, is it a member of your class?

Comment: Yes, `coll` is the private member of class

Answer (score 2):

You have violated the following rules with the mongo-cxx-driver

1. A `mongocxx::instance` object must be made available throughout your use of the server. There must be one and only one. You violated this by creating this `mongocxx::instance instance{};` on the call stack in your function `Dbconnection::DBConnection()` which means it gets destroyed when the function goes out of scope.
2. All objects derived from a `mongocxx::client` object (e.g. `mongocxx::database` and `mongocxx::collection`) must not outlive the `mongocxx::client` that derived them. You violated this in your function `Dbconnection::DBConnection()` where the `mongocxx::client` is created on the call stack and is destroyed once it’s out of scope. Using `client["testdb"]["testcollection"].find({});` after this in `Dbconnection::loadData()` gives errors.

- [mongocxx::instance](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classmongocxx_1_1instance.html#details)
- [mongocxx::client](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classmongocxx_1_1client.html#details)

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the `mongocxx::collection` object is required to be a subset of the lifetime of the `mongocxx::client` object that created it. You have violated that constraint by obtaining the `mongocxx::client` object in the constructor, then obtaining and storing the `mongocxx::collection` object in (what is presumably a) member variable of the class, and then allowing the `mongocxx::client` object to be destroyed. The subsequent use of the `mongocxx::collection` object in `loadData` invalid.